# Android: how to deny access to the my accounts(Accounts&sync) from other applications?

Tags: android

Android: how to deny access to the my accounts(Accounts&sync)  from other applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default android os don't allow other app to access your component. So you don't need to worry about it. You have to change permission in case you want to allow other app to access your component.